# Android Safe Args, nav_graph and enums error: Comparison of incompatible enums is always unsuccessful

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-safe-args

I'm experiencing a weird issue here with Safe Args when trying to pass an argument of a type that's an enum defined inside such fragment class. Some code, for clarification.

This is the enum, as it is defined inside the "EvaluationFragment" kotlin class:

```
    enum class EnrollmentOutcome(vararg labels: String) {
        Accepted("AUTO_APPROVED"), Rejected("AUTO_DECLINED"), Reviewing("REVIEW_REQUIRED"), Unknown(
            "UNAVAILABLE"
        );

        private val outcomeLabels: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        companion object {
            fun fromString(label: String): EnrollmentOutcome {
                return when {
                    Accepted.outcomeLabels.contains(label) -> {
                        Accepted
                    }
                    Rejected.outcomeLabels.contains(label) -> {
                        Rejected
                    }
                    Reviewing.outcomeLabels.contains(label) -> {
                        Reviewing
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Unknown
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        init {
            outcomeLabels.addAll(listOf(*labels))
        }
    }
```

This is the involved fragment entry as defined in nav_graph.xml file:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/evaluationFragment"
        android:name="com.whatever.domain.EvaluationFragment"
        android:label="fragment_evaluation"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_evaluation" >
        <argument
            android:name="outcome"
            app:argType="com.whatever.domain.EvaluationFragment$EnrollmentOutcome"
            android:defaultValue="Unknown" />
    </fragment>
```

Then I have this inside the EvaluationFragment class as a private field:

```
private val args: EvaluationFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

And this inside a method in such class too, that's where the error happens:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        when (args.outcome) {
            EnrollmentOutcome.Accepted -> {
                outcomeTitle.setText(R.string.registration_accepted)
                outcomeIcon.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.drawable.ic_check_circle_green_48dp
                    )
                )
                outcomeDescription.setText(R.string.registration_description_accepted)
            }
            EnrollmentOutcome.Rejected -> {
                outcomeTitle.setText(R.string.registration_declined)
                outcomeDescription.setText(R.string.registration_description_declined)
                outcomeIcon.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.drawable.ic_error_red_48dp
                    )
                )
            }
            EnrollmentOutcome.Reviewing -> {
                outcomeTitle.setText(R.string.registration_reviewing)
                outcomeDescription.setText(R.string.registration_description_reviewing)
                outcomeIcon.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.drawable.ic_info_blue_48dp
                    )
                )
            }
            EnrollmentOutcome.Unknown -> {
                outcomeTitle.setText(R.string.registration_error)
                outcomeDescription.setText(R.string.registration_description_error)
                outcomeIcon.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_error_red_48dp
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that in each of these when branches the enum item is underlined in red by Android Studio and show this error:

> Comparison of incompatible enums '[ERROR : com.whatever.domain.EvaluationFragment$EnrollmentOutcome]' and 'EvaluationFragment.EnrollmentOutcome' is always unsuccessful

In spite of that, the code not only does build perfectly well but it works exactly as expected.

In any case I'd like to know *why* is Android Studio throwing an error there and how I could get rid of it and still use the enum in safe args (I mean, I could workaround it easily by passing a String instead and doing the required conversions for which I already have a method in the enum itself, but that kinda defeat the point of using Safe Args, doesn't it?).

Thanks a lot in advance,
Fran

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing that error from Android Studio but I do know how to remove that error.

Within your nav_graph.xml you have the argType set to the enum within a class. If you move the enum outside of the class, then change the argType to match to where it was moved to (just remove the class name with the $) then it'll have no issues

Comment: Thanks James, I'll try to confirm that. In any case is clearly a bug in AS since it should be able to deal also with nested enums, which are quite common and convenient.